# Eigen - Levenberg Marquardt algorithm: invalid template arguments on definition of permutation

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, eigen, levenberg-marquardt

I'm trying to use the Eigen implementation of Levenberg Marquardt algorithm on a Android application. In order to use Eigen, I'm using Android NDK and jni. I've already tested Eigen with simple calculations (like matrix creation and vector sums) and it works perfectly. However, when I tried to use the Levenberg Marquardt algorithm I got some errors on the LevenbergMarquardt.h file from Eigen's library.

First, here is my code. I based on [this code](http://techblog.rga.com/determining-indoor-position-using-ibeacon/):

```
Eigen::MatrixXd matrix(count, 3);

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    Eigen::VectorXd t(3);
    t << x[i], y[i], accuracy[i];
    matrix.row(i) = t;
}

distance_functor functor(matrix, count);
Eigen::NumericalDiff<distance_functor> numDiff(functor);
Eigen::LevenbergMarquardt<Eigen::NumericalDiff<distance_functor>,double> lm(numDiff);

lm.parameters.maxfev = 2000;
lm.parameters.xtol = 1.49012e-08;
lm.parameters.ftol = 1.49012e-08;
lm.parameters.gtol = 0;
lm.parameters.epsfcn = 0;
Eigen::LevenbergMarquardtSpace::Status ret = lm.minimize(poseResult);
```

And those are the error that I got. The first two errors are in Eigen's library, and the last one is on the LevenbergMarquardt object creation. I've also included the respective line of code of the error, following the message:

> Invalid template
>   arguments LevenbergMarquardt.h    /jnimath/jni/unsupported/Eigen/src/LevenbergMarquardt   line
>   121   Semantic Error
>
> ```
> typedef PermutationMatrix<Dynamic,Dynamic> PermutationType;
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Invalid template
>   arguments LevenbergMarquardt.h    /jnimath/jni/unsupported/Eigen/src/NonLinearOptimization    line
>   103   Semantic Error
>
> ```
> PermutationMatrix<Dynamic,Dynamic> permutation;
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Invalid template arguments    test.cpp    /jnimath/jni    line 47 Semantic
>   Error
>
> Eigen::LevenbergMarquardt,double> lm(numDiff);

The first two errors are really strange because there are some other typedefs using Dynamic and they are not throwing errors.

Also, I noticed that I got some symbol errors on the compilation, which are:

> Symbol
>   'YOU_MIXED_DIFFERENT_NUMERIC_TYPES__YOU_NEED_TO_USE_THE_CAST_METHOD_OF_MATRIXBASE_TO_CAST_NUMERIC_TYPES_EXPLICITLY'
>   could not be resolved Matrix.h    /jnimath/jni/Eigen/src/Core line
>   277   Semantic Error
>
> ---
>
> Symbol 'YOU_TRIED_CALLING_A_VECTOR_METHOD_ON_A_MATRIX' could not be
>   resolved  Matrix.h    /jnimath/jni/Eigen/src/Core line 224    Semantic Error

So, I have two questions:

Why am I getting errors on those lines?

Does anyone know how to fix that problem?

Thank you