# Trilateration in Android using iBeacons

Tags: android, ibeacon, eigen, altbeacon, levenberg-marquardt

We want to implement some kind of indoor position determination using iBeacons.
[This article seems really interesting](http://techblog.rga.com/determining-indoor-position-using-ibeacon/), in which the author implemented the Non-linear Least Squares Triangulation, using the Eigen C++ library and the Levenberg Marquardt algorithm. Since Eigen is written in C++, I tried to use JNI and Android NDK in order to use it but it throws a [lot of errors that I have no idea how to solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615684/eigen-levenberg-marquardt-algorithm-invalid-template-arguments-on-definition) and I couldn´t find anything online. I also tried to use Jeigen, but it does not have all the functions that we need.

So, my questions are:

1. Has someone ever implemented some kind of Trilateration using
   beacons in Android?
2. Do you think that using Eigen+JNI+NDK is a good solution? If yes,
       have you ever implemented Levenberg Marquardt using that
       combination?
3. Are there better options than the Levenberg Marquardt algorithm for calculating the trilateration in a Android application?

Comment: Did you try http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/download.html ?

Comment: I gave an example of how to implement some Eigen funtions with Java [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046585/cholmod-in-java/30526005#30526005).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this library: https://github.com/lemmingapex/Trilateration

uses Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm from Apache Commons Math.

For example..
into the [TrilaterationTest.java](https://github.com/lemmingapex/trilateration/blob/master/src/test/java/com/lemmingapex/trilateration/TrilaterationTest.java)

you can see:

```
double[][] positions = new double[][] { { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 2.0, 1.0 } };
double[] distances = new double[] { 0.0, 1.0 };

TrilaterationFunction trilaterationFunction = new TrilaterationFunction(positions, distances);
NonLinearLeastSquaresSolver solver = new NonLinearLeastSquaresSolver(trilaterationFunction, new LevenbergMarquardtOptimizer());

double[] expectedPosition = new double[] { 1.0, 1.0 };
Optimum optimum = solver.solve();
testResults(expectedPosition, 0.0001, optimum);
```

but if you see the objectivec example https://github.com/RGADigital/indoor_navigation_iBeacons/blob/show-work/ios/Group5iBeacons/Debug/Managers/Location/NonLinear/NonLinear.mm you can note that the accuracy is used as an assessment parameter and not the distance.

Comment: Works great!  When using the trilateration algorithm, make sure to convert (lat, long, alt) into Cartesian coordinates (x, y, z) as required by the library.