# How to map in real time using indoor beacons on Android

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, indoor-positioning-system

How to map in real time using indoor beacons on Android? Did tests using the [SDK Estimote](http://estimote.com/) however, they do not have support for Android in indoor and do not have a method that returns the distance to the beacon.
With that, I'm using [Alt SDK](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/index.html) that returns me the distance.
But not her how to solve these doubts:

1) create a map (2D or 3D Google Maps type) with the location map of the inside of a room or shop for example.

2) show the location of the user's route to the beacon.

3) how to deal with the route to the beacon avoiding collision enters walls on the map?

4) how to locate the user's position in relation to beacons and know the position x, y or lat, long each beacon?

5) I saw this project [trilateration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849672/trilateration-in-android-using-ibeacons) but not your using to address the above questions.

6) need to use the GPS plus Bluetooth or just the Bluetooth solves?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using one of the existing solutions, as this is a huge task that you're trying to achieve. I work for Proximi.io, that is a unified positioning platform. We provide beacon trilateration and showing your exact positioning on top of an indoor map based on that info. However, we don't have routing features. For that I would recommend checking out Steerpath, http://www.steerpath.com/. They specialize in beacon-based navigation, and deal with the wall issue.

Answer (score 1):

Building an indoor navigation system is very complex.  Beacon toolkits can tell you roughly how far you are from a stationary transmitter, but cannot tell you direction.  It is just a tiny building block of a big system. A beacon is to an indoor navigation system as a brick is to a building.

You have brought up several important requirements and there are many others, including:

- Building a system to record beacon positions in a known coordinate frame, and send them to your app
- Transform beacon coordinate frame estimated positions to map coordinate frame for displaying a blue dot.

How to build such a system is simply beyond the scope of questions that can be answered properly on StackOverflow.