# How to use Altbeacon Library for indoor positioning?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon, eddystone, indoor-positioning-system, trilateration

So, I was developing an Android Application which uses AltBeacon Library for detecting beacons and get its advertising content, but I don't seem to find a good solution as to how I can use this library for indoor positioning, I was searching through google for some answers, and I think its a better option to use an SDK for indoor-positioning, since I need information like the geolocation(lat,long etc) which is not easy to calculate using Altbeacon, I am a bit confused on how to start this, need suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saying you want to make an indoor positioning system with a beacon detection library is kind of like saying you want to make a house out of a pile of bricks.  While it is certainly possible, it is a huge amount of work that requires all kinds of other tools and technologies. A library lets you detect beacons is just one small thing that is needed.

Rather than taking on the huge job of trying to build one yourself, I would research a dedicated indoor positioning SDKs.

See a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38658217/how-to-map-in-real-time-using-indoor-beacons-on-android?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew it would obviously not be an easy task to create such a system using altbeacon, I should be looking for SDKs that at least give me a kick starter for this project, any open source SDK that you can recommend, that can help me in this aspect ?